# Regular expressions C# - is it possible to extract matches while matching?

Tags: c#, regex, extract

Say, I have a string that I need to verify the correct format of; e.g. `RR1234566-001` (2 letters, 7 digits, dash, 1 or more digits). I use something like:

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(patternString);
        if (regex.IsMatch(stringToMatch))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

This works to tell me whether the `stringToMatch` follows the pattern defined by `patternString`.  What I need though (and I end up extracting these later) are:
`123456` and `001` -- i.e. portions of the `stringToMatch`.

Please note that this is NOT a question about how to construct regular expressions. What I am asking is: "Is there a way to match and extract values simultaneously without having to use a split function later?"

Comment: Note that you can just return:  
  
`return regex.IsMatch(...) // code from the question` or
`return match.Success  // code from the accepted solution`  
  
returns in if/else are not needed :)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use regex groups to accomplish that.  For example, this regex:

```
(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)
```

Let's match a telephone number with this regex:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)");
var match = regex.Match("123-4567890");
if (match.Success)
    ....
```

If it matches, you will find the first three digits in:

```
match.Groups[1].Value
```

And the second 7 digits in:

```
match.Groups[2].Value
```

P.S. In C#, you can use a @"" style string to avoid escaping backslashes.  For example, @"\hi\" equals "\\hi\\".  Useful for regular expressions and paths.

P.S.2. The first group is stored in Group[1], not Group[0] as you would expect.  That's because Group[0] contains the entire matched string.

Comment: +1 Very thorough! I'd add one thing though, the reason that you start on match.Groups[1] and not [0] is because [0] contains the entire matched string.

Comment: Named groups are much harder to get wrong, use `new Regex(@"(?<areacode>\d\d\d)-(?<number>\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)");` instead.

Answer (score 18):

Use grouping and Matches instead.

I.e.:

```
// NOTE: pseudocode.
Regex re = new Regex("(\\d+)-(\\d+)");
Match m = re.Match(stringToMatch))

if (m.Success) {
  String part1 = m.Groups[1].Value;
  String part2 = m.Groups[2].Value;
  return true;
} 
else {
  return false;
}
```

You can also name the matches, like this:

```
Regex re = new Regex("(?<Part1>\\d+)-(?<Part2>\\d+)");
```

and access like this

```
  String part1 = m.Groups["Part1"].Value;
  String part2 = m.Groups["Part2"].Value;
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use parentheses to capture groups of characters:

```
string test = "RR1234566-001";

// capture 2 letters, then 7 digits, then a hyphen, then 1 or more digits
string rx = @"^([A-Za-z]{2})(\d{7})(\-)(\d+)$";

Match m = Regex.Match(test, rx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);    // RR
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);    // 1234566
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].Value);    // -
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[4].Value);    // 001
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the right regex... btw if you use IgnoreCase, you can use [a-z] instead of [A-Za-z].

Answer (score -1):

```
string text = "RR1234566-001";
string regex = @"^([A-Z a-z]{2})(\d{7})(\-)(\d+)";
Match mtch = Regex.Matches(text,regex);
if (mtch.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);    
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);    
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].Value);    
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[4].Value);    
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```