# Extracting character-number pairs from a string

Tags: c#, regex

Character-values pairs are received continuously from serial port in the following format

```
h135v48s167
```

,where h has value 135, v has 48 and s has 167 (the numeric values ranges from 0 to 2000).
I am using if-else statement to perform specific actions based on values of `h`, `v` and `s`.

I tried regex as `v(\d+)` to get the value of v, which gives `v48` as result.

- 1. How can i get the numeric value only?
- 2. I have to use regex 3 times to get the values of `h`, `v` and `s`. Can a single regexp statement works?
- 3. Is there any other better way without using regex?

Following is the section of the code where I am using this -

```
        if (port.IsOpen) {
      if (port.BytesToRead > 0) {
          //  port.WriteLine ("p");

          string data = port.ReadExisting ();

          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (data)) {

              h = Regex.Match (data, @"h\d+").Value;
              v = Regex.Match (data, @"v\d+").Value;
              s = Regex.Match (data, @"s\d+").Value;

              if (h > 150) {
                  // do something
              }

              if (v < 30) {
                  // do something
              }

          } else {
              // default
          }

      }
  }
```

Comment: Your first question is a dupe of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841883/regular-expressions-c-sharp-is-it-possible-to-extract-matches-while-matching). As for the second and third, please share your code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew code added

Comment: So, the only real blocker here is the absense of the capturing group, use `h = Regex.Match (data, @"h(\d+)")?.Groups[1].Value;` etc.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Correct me if I am wrong but the post you have mentioned is giving solution for a particular format. In my case the numeric values can change in length from 0 to 2000.

Comment: The post shows how to extract part of a match, just what you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks that was the exact answer to Q1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex is fine. To allow for arbitrary letters, use `[a-z]` (or use `[hvs]` instead if you only want to catch these letters). You may capture both the letter and the number by parantheses and refer to them using the [Match.Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups) collection.

```
var data = "h135v48s167";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(data, @"([a-z])(\d+)"))
{
    var variable = m.Groups[1].Value[0];
    var value = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[2].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", variable, value);
    switch (variable)
    {
        case 'h':
            // do something
            break;
        case 'v':
            // do something
            break;
        case 's':
            // do something
            break;
    }
}
```

gives:

```
h=135
v=48
s=167
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is very compact and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "h135v48s167";
            string pattern = "h(?'h'[^v]+)v(?'v'[^s]+)s(?'s'.*)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input,pattern);

            string h = match.Groups["h"].Value;
            string v = match.Groups["v"].Value;
            string s = match.Groups["s"].Value;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there any specific reason for using `.*` only with s. I found `h(?'h'.*)v(?'v'.*)s(?'s'.*)` to be working too.

Comment: Not really.  The .* means any character zero or more times.  The .* often reads too may characters in the middle of a pattern.  So I try to restrict the pattern.   Using \d+ will also work if you are just expecting digits.  I like to make code easy to figure out in case somebody else has to modify in the future.  Using .* somebody else may not understand what the code is doing.